# LSB-propagating left shift, conceptual equivalent of sign-propagating right shift

Tags: bitwise-operators

How would I write something that fills with the right-most bit (`<<<` is used to denote this non-existent operator):

`1 <<< 7: "11111111"` and `0 <<< 7: "00000000"`

`9 <<< 1: "10011"` and `10 <<< 7: "10100000000"`

as in the reverse of the [Sign-propagating right shift](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Bitwise_Operators#Right_shift) (which fills with the left-most digit):

`-256 >> 8: "11111111111111111111111100000000" >> "11111111111111111111111111111111"`

and

`16777215 >> 8: "00000000111111111111111111111111" >> "00000000000000001111111111111111"`?

Comment: It's unclear what you are trying to do here from your description.  It looks like you are attempting to use bitmasks, however.

Comment: @RobertHarvey I want to fill with the previous right most digit.

Comment: @RobertHarvey Could you check again, please? I changed the question so it would become more clear what I'm after.

Comment: Your question is suffering from bad examples.  What should 15 <<< 3 give us?

Comment: What @CandiedOrange said.  It's difficult to tell from the examples what the result should be.

Comment: @CandiedOrange Since 15 is odd, it would shift everything to the right 3 places and fill with ones. If it was 16, it would have been the same behavior as `<<`.

Comment: If the right most bit is zero do a normal left shift.  If it is one the perform a loop for the number of shift, and in the loop shift one left then OR one.  15 <<< 3 = 127

Comment: @dbasnett That takes a lot of actions for something that can be done in 4...

Comment: @Martijn - you should have shown those four 'actions' in your post.

Comment: @dbasnett no, they were provided in an answer given before your comment. Why would I include that in the post?

Comment: @Martijn - those actions were just pseudo code.  Reversing bits, if you followed the link, takes several 'actions' all on its own, and it is done twice.  The easy way is to do what I suggested, or check bit 0, and if it is one raise two to the power of the shift value and subtract one, then do a normal left shift and OR that value.  The tricky part will be magnitude related.

Comment: @dbasnett I should have used better terminology in my comment. I was referring to the last code snippet CandiedOrange posted which used 4 operations max. That was a mistake on my part.

Comment: @Martijn - the last example given by CandiedOrange is good.  That seems to be the way to go.  Good luck.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Well if I didn't care about performance (and I never do until I have to) I'd do it the simplest way I can think of.

Presuming a language (such as c) where I have the [arithmetic right shift](https://www.cs.umd.edu/class/sum2003/cmsc311/Notes/BitOp/bitshift.html) (what you call a sign-propagating right shift), and presuming I know how to [reverse the bits in a register](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/746171/best-algorithm-for-bit-reversal-from-msb-lsb-to-lsb-msb-in-c) then I can build your "left shift equivalent" like so:

- reverse bits
- arithmetic right shift x bits
- reverse bits

  ```
  1 <<< 7: "11111111" 

  00000001 <- 1
  10000000 <- reverse   
  11111111 <- arithmetic right shift (7) 
  11111111 <- reverse

  0 <<< 7: "00000000"
  00000000 <- 0
  00000000 <- reverse   
  00000000 <- arithmetic right shift (7)
  00000000 <- reverse   

  15 <<< 3: "01111111"
  00001111 <- 15
  11110000 <- reverse   
  11111110 <- arithmetic right shift (3)
  01111111 <- reverse
  ```

This is likely slow but uses well tested code and is conceptually simple. So at the least it can be the bedrock for tests against any faster methods.

This next idea is not tested but off the top of my head a more direct route would be to left shift, mask out the bit that you need propagate, subtract 1, and `or` with the result of the shift.

```
    15 <<< 3 :"01111111"
    00001111 <- 15
    01111000 <- left shift 
    00001000 <- mask out propagating bit.  If result is zero, return the shift
    00000111 <- subtract 1
    01111111 <- OR with result of shift (01111000)
```

I wouldn't trust this until I'd tested it.  But this seems to work:

```
    result = ((n&1)==1)?(n<<x|(1<<x)-1):(n<<x);
```

Done without branching, a more [performant](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11227809/why-is-processing-a-sorted-array-faster-than-an-unsorted-array/11227902#11227902) version, suggested by @ErikEidt, would be:

```
    y = (n & 1); 
    result = ((n << x) | ((y << x) - y));
```

Done this way the shift (`n<<x`) is `OR`'ed with zero's when not propagating so there is no need to branch.

Comment: After `y = (n & 1)`, wouldn't it be simpler to do `result = ((n + y) << x) - y`?

Answer (score 2):

Capture the low bit before the shift. Then shift left by the desired amount.  Now test the captured low bit.  If the low bit was `0`, there's nothing left to do.  If it was `1`, and you shifted by, say, `5` then you can OR into the shifted result the value: `(1<<5)-1`, which will be 5 one bits in the lowest position.  If you have the shift amount in a variable, then substitute that for the 5.

Comment: This is exactly what I was thinking but I thought there had to be a better way than having this in an if statement.

Comment: @ErikEidt I agree that it would be [performant to get rid of the `if`](http://stackoverflow.com/a/11227902/1493294). However, I don't see how your solution from this comment works.  To me it sounds like you're saying: `((toShift & 1) << x) | ((toShift & 1) << x)-1;`  Which doesn't work.  15 <<< 3 : 15.  Have I got this wrong?

Comment: No, my bad.  It needs to be `y = toShift & 1;` then the left shift,  then OR in `(y<<x)-y` (instead of`(y<<x)-1`).

Comment: @ErikEidt that works.  I tested it expressed as: `((n << x) | (((n & 1) << x) - (n & 1)))`  In this form when nothing is propagating the shift is `or`'ed with zeros.